# Kendo UI Validator - Handling inputs with identical name attributes

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, kendo-asp.net-mvc, kendo-validator

I currently have a form similar to the below:

```
<form action="/" method="post" id="myForm">
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="rowValue" class="rowValue">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="rowValue" class="rowValue">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="rowValue" class="rowValue">
    </div>
    <div class="row">
        <input type="text" name="rowValue" class="rowValue">
    </div>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

*A little background: JS is used to inject X amount of new "rows" into the form.*

I tried using:

```
var myForm = $('#myForm').kendoValidator({
    /* rules/messages go here*/
}).data('kendoValidator');

myForm.validate();
```

I only get one error message showing up on the first `input[name='rowValue']`.

### [JS Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/fmpeyton/5c9d2p0c/)

My suspicion is Kendo Validator needs unique name attributes to validate correctly. This is a shame, since lots of backend languages have the ability to accept identical name attributes, as they concatenate the values or convert them into an array or collection (ASP.NET).

#### Is there a way to have Kendo UI Validator validate form fields with identical name attributes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your suspicion is correct. You could adjust the validator for your use case like this:

```
kendo.ui.Validator.prototype.validateInput = function (input) {
    input = $(input);

    var that = this,
        template = that._errorTemplate,
        result = that._checkValidity(input),
        valid = result.valid,
        className = ".k-invalid-msg",
        fieldName = (input.attr("name") || ""),
        lbl = input.parent().find("span" + className).hide(),
        messageText;

    input.removeAttr("aria-invalid");

    if (!valid) {
        messageText = that._extractMessage(input, result.key);
        that._errors[fieldName] = messageText;
        var messageLabel = $(template({
            message: messageText
        }));

        that._decorateMessageContainer(messageLabel, fieldName);

        if (!lbl.replaceWith(messageLabel).length) {
            messageLabel.insertAfter(input);
        }
        messageLabel.show();

        input.attr("aria-invalid", true);
    }  
    input.toggleClass("k-invalid", !valid);

    return valid;
};
```

Note that there are a few simplifications in this method, so it may break on certain corner cases.

([demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rwy0oz29/))

Comment: GREAT solution. Don't know why I didn't think of this. Thanks for your help!